# How to bring `Hide Me` button to top of webpage from bottom after image present at top is made to hide?

Tags: javascript

I Have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        function myEvent(){
            if(document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML=="Hide Me"){
                document.getElementById('demo1').src='none';
                document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML='Display Me';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('demo1').src="deepika.jpg";
                document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML="Hide Me";
                changeCSS();
            }
        }

        function changeCSS(){
            document.getElementById('demo1').style.height="500";
            document.getElementById('demo1').style.width="400";
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <img src="deepika.jpg" id="demo1" height="500" width="400"><br>
    <button type="button" id="demo2" onclick=myEvent()>Hide Me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

After clicking on `Hide Me` button I get this page:

[image]

Now I want to completely remove the picture block and bring `Display Me` button to top of the page. How can I do so?

I want to use plain JavaScript only and no JQuery

Comment: After you clicked on Hide me button, set the style for `#demo1` to `display: none;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you want to toggle the display of image upon button click. You can use the below updated myEvent function:

```
function myEvent(){
    if(document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML=="Hide Me"){
        document.getElementById('demo1').src='none';
        document.getElementById('demo1').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML='Display Me';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('demo1').style.display = "";
        document.getElementById('demo1').src="deepika.jpg";
        document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML="Hide Me";
        changeCSS();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I changed your code slightly by writing `style.display='block';`